# Dependency for add_jar cmake

Tags: cmake

I am actually generating java source files dynamically through code generators. I want to create jar file containing the java files created through this code generator.

```
add_custom_target(lang ALL)

add_custom_command(
        TARGET lang
        COMMAND ${Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE} ${CMD_PRG_LNG} --proto_path=${PROTO_FILES} ${COMMONS}/*.proto")
```

If I run my cmake without add_jar command, it successfully run and generate java files in the respective folders. But, if I add add_jar

```
add_jar(${JAR_NAME} ${JAVA_SOURCES})
```

The above instruction fails with the following error message.

```
Scanning dependencies of target ProtoJava
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../protoJava/Data.java', needed by 'CMakeFiles/ProtoJava.dir/java_compiled_ProtoJava'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ProtoJava.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ProtoJava.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to get the jar file created? I tried putting add_jar inside add_custom_command under the same target as java file creation.

```
add_custom_command(
        TARGET lang_java
        COMMAND add_jar(${JAR_NAME} ${JAVA_SOURCES}))
```

but it errors out with message

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
CMakeFiles/lang_java.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'lang_java' failed
make[2]: *** [lang_java] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/lang_java.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lang_java.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to fix this one?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of this in your CMake code? For example, it is unclear what the `ProtoJava` target is. What are the `JAR_NAME` and `JAVA_SOURCES` variables set to?

Comment: With [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_dependencies.html) command you can create a dependency between `${JAR_NAME}` target, created by `add_jar`, and `lang` target, created by you. So you target will be executed before the jar begins to compile.